# null is not an object (evaluating 'internalInstance.getHostNode') in React Native component

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

My React Native application has a component that is supposed to show a scrollable list. I'm also using [React Native Elements](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-elements), although leaving that out doesn't seem to make a big difference.

My component looks like this:

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
        this.state = { ds: ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.myItems) };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Some text here</Text>
                <List>
                    <ListView dataSource={ this.state.ds } renderRow={ renderRow } />
                </List>
            </View>
        );
    }
};
```

Where `renderRow` is declared outside the class, since it doesn't need its state, as:

```
const renderRow = (rowData, sectionId) => {
    return (
        <ListItem
            key={ sectionId }
            title={ rowData.myProp }
            subtitle={ rowData.myOtherProp }
        />
    );
};
```

Besides, removing the `<List>` with its children doesn't seem to make a difference, either.

From the logging (not included in the code, for brevity) I can see that the component `constructor` runs without problems. The `render` method isn't invoked, though. In `adb logcat` output (I'm using the Android simulator) I see the following:

```
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: null is not an object (evaluating 'internalInstance.getHostNode')
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: getHostNode@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:16594:24
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: getHostNode@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:18320:35
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: getHostNode@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:16594:36
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: getHostNode@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:18320:35
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: getHostNode@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:16594:36
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: getHostNode@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:18320:35
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: getHostNode@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:16594:36
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: getHostNode@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:18320:35
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: getHostNode@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:16594:36
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: updateChildren@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:17792:47
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: _reconcilerUpdateChildren@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:17341:36
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: _updateChildren@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:17445:48
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: updateChildren@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:17432:21
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: receiveComponent@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:14715:20
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: receiveComponent@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:16656:34
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: _updateRenderedComponent@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:18688:33
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: _performComponentUpdate@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:18658:30
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: updateComponent@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:18579:29
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: receiveComponent@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:18481:21
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: receiveComponent@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:16656:34
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: _updateRenderedComponent@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:18688:33
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: _performComponentUpdate@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:18658:30
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: updateComponent@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:18579:29
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: receiveComponent@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:18481:21
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: receiveComponent@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:16656:34
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: _updateRenderedComponent@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:18688:33
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: _performComponentUpdate@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:18658:30
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: updateComponent@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:18579:29
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: performUpdateIfNecessary@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:18495:21
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: performUpdateIfNecessary@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:16688:42
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: runBatchedUpdates@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:16299:41
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: perform@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:17035:16
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: perform@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:17035:16
10-16 14:02:34.507 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: perform@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&m
10-16 14:02:34.527 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: Warning: performUpdateIfNecessary: Unexpected batch number (current 17, pending 15)
10-16 14:02:34.800 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: Warning: performUpdateIfNecessary: Unexpected batch number (current 21, pending 15)
10-16 14:02:34.801 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: Warning: performUpdateIfNecessary: Unexpected batch number (current 22, pending 20)
10-16 14:02:34.905 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: Warning: performUpdateIfNecessary: Unexpected batch number (current 26, pending 15)
10-16 14:02:34.908 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: Warning: performUpdateIfNecessary: Unexpected batch number (current 27, pending 20)
10-16 14:02:35.191 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: Warning: performUpdateIfNecessary: Unexpected batch number (current 31, pending 15)
10-16 14:02:35.191 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: Warning: performUpdateIfNecessary: Unexpected batch number (current 32, pending 20)
10-16 14:02:35.192 10161 10205 W ReactNativeJS: Warning: performUpdateIfNecessary: Unexpected batch number (current 33, pending 30)
```

I'm using

- react 15.3.2
- react-native 0.35.0
- react-native-elements 0.6.2

My question is two-fold: how can I troubleshoot what's going on (why is my `render()` method not invoked, for instance) and what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned out that the actual solution was not in the use of `ListView` or `List`. Some of the logging statements inside `render()` caused the `render()` method to fail - silently. RN then attempted to re-render the component, which caused the log message as shown in the question to continuously re-appear until the app was killed.

Comment: Ran into something similar, was using a [controlled radio](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/#controlled) ToggleButton but skipped the ```name``` field, which threw off the render method giving me the ```getHostNode``` error.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I troubleshoot what's going on (why is my render() method not invoked, for instance)

Use `console.debug(msg)` or `console.error(msg)`, etc to log messages in your code and then view your console logs by running on your terminal `react-native log-android` for Android or `react-native log-ios` for iOS, from your project folder.

> what am I doing wrong here?

There are two problems in your code. First, the `cloneRowsWithData`, as the documentation says, *does NOT clone the data in this data source. It simply passes the functions defined at construction to a new data source with the data specified*. Therefore, you need to assign the result of this function to another variable. Second, the state is an object. You define `ds` but you leave it unassigned. So what you need to do is this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
    this.state = { dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.myItems) };
}
```

And then in your `render()` change the ListView's `dataSource` prop to:

`dataSource={ this.state.dataSource }`

Comment: Thanks for the hint about `cloneWithRows`. My state now contains the result of the `cloneWithRows` invocation (I used the new [ES6 syntax for object instantiation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions)). The problem still persists, though, with the exact same error message being logged.